# ODS PDF with sgplot: How to make one TOC bookmark per page (with two graphs per page)

Tags: pdf, sas, tableofcontents, ods

I am creating PDFs using ODS with two graphs per page. Both graphs have the same value for a type variable, 'month' below. I want to create a TOC bookmark for each page, which refers to the value of the highest-level variable ('year' below). There could be any number of values for 'year', but only two 'month' values per year. I don't want multiple levels of bookmarks, just one per page.

I looked at ODS document, but I don't know if it is possible to use that for this purpose if I have an indefinite number of graphs.

Here is what I have now:

```
data new;
do year = 1 to 5;
    do month = 1 to 2;
        do day = 1 to 10;
            emp = year*month*day;
            output;
        end;
    end;
end;
run;

ods pdf file='K:\brent\test_graphs_pages.pdf' startpage=never;
    proc sgplot data=new;
    by year month;
    series x = day y = emp;
    run;
ods pdf close;
```

It is giving me three levels of bookmarks, and two bookmarks per page. How can I get just one per page? Also, why does the bookmark for year 2 link to the page with year 1 on it?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps startpage=never is a problem

Comment: Thanks, I tried removing that and the output had only one graph per page - I need two graphs per page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This definitely sounds like a PROC DOCUMENT problem.  You may need to use the macro language to generate the code, as some of this I don't think is fully automatable inside `proc document` (primarily the `setlabel` piece), but the broad strokes would be:

- `ods document` to generate the document
- `proc document` then to `move` with `where` the month=1 and month=2 entries to a single `dir`
- `proc document` with `setlabel` to use the `#BYVAL(YEAR)` to set the label correctly
- `proc document` `replay` to output the document.

This is the first part - you'd still want to customize the labels, and like I said you'd need to automate this with the macro language.

```
data new;
  do year = 1 to 5;
    do month = 1 to 2;
        do day = 1 to 10;
            emp = year*month*day;
            output;
        end;
    end;
  end;
run;


ods document name=TOCtest(write);
ods pdf file='h:\temp\test_graphs_pages_before.pdf' startpage=never;
    proc sgplot data=new;
    by year month;
    series x = day y = emp;
    run;
ods pdf close;
ods document close;


ods listing;
proc document name=TOCtest;
list / levels=all; run;
make \Year1;
move \SGPlot#1\ByGroup1#1\SGPlot#1  to \Year1#1;
move \SGPlot#1\ByGroup2#1\SGPlot#1  to \Year1#1;
delete \SGPlot#1\ByGroup1#1;
delete \SGPlot#1\ByGroup2#1;


make \Year2;
move \SGPlot#1\ByGroup3#1\SGPlot#1  to \Year2#1;
move \SGPlot#1\ByGroup4#1\SGPlot#1  to \Year2#1;
delete \SGPlot#1\ByGroup3#1;
delete \SGPlot#1\ByGroup4#1;

make \Year3;
move \SGPlot#1\ByGroup5#1\SGPlot#1  to \Year3#1;
move \SGPlot#1\ByGroup6#1\SGPlot#1  to \Year3#1;
delete \SGPlot#1\ByGroup5#1;
delete \SGPlot#1\ByGroup6#1;

make \Year4;
move \SGPlot#1\ByGroup7#1\SGPlot#1  to \Year4#1;
move \SGPlot#1\ByGroup8#1\SGPlot#1  to \Year4#1;
delete \SGPlot#1\ByGroup7#1;
delete \SGPlot#1\ByGroup8#1;

make \Year5;
move \SGPlot#1\ByGroup9#1\SGPlot#1  to \Year5#1;
move \SGPlot#1\ByGroup10#1\SGPlot#1  to \Year5#1;
delete \SGPlot#1\ByGroup9#1;
delete \SGPlot#1\ByGroup10#1;
run;
list /details levels=all; run;

ods pdf file="h:\temp\test_graph_pages_after.pdf" startpage=never;
replay ^
run;
ods pdf close;
```

This still exhibits the "one off" issue you noticed before.  That seems to be unavoidable with the startpage=never - I'm not sure about a workaround there, that might be worth contacting support@sas.com as it might be a bug.  They had a similar bug in 9.4m1/m2 that was fixed, but is not identical.